# How do I force Django queryset return datetime field in current timezone?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have Django model:

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I get created_at value by queryset, it always return to me the datetime value with `tzinfo=<UTC>` like this:

```
Deal.objects.filter(id=62).values('created_at')
<QuerySet [{'created_at': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 26, 4, 10, 54, 997000, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]>
```

How do I force queryset return datetime value in current timezone (e.g Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django always saves datetimes in UTC, and they are usually returned in UTC as well (depending on the database and database adapter settings). You normally select a timezone by using [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate). That affects various things, like the way datetimes are displayed in templates.

If you want to explicitly convert the timezone for some reason, you can easily do that with [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime). For example:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
deals_utc = Deal.objects.filter(id=62).values("created_at")
deals_local = {"created_at": localtime(dt, tz) for dt in deals_utc.values()}
```

Comment: Converting explicitly is a bad idea if it is to be reflected in the whole application. How it can be done implicitly? `activate()` doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score -1):

In your settings.py file, change TIME_ZONE value.

```
TIME_ZONE='Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'
```